# Вывод из таблицы mySQL в цикл

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте , помогите разобраться. У меня есть таблица в mySQL, мне нужно из неё вывести значения с поля в цикл, но нужно сделать так чтоб контент выводился для конкретного `id` элемента [image]

На скрине указал что например для `id 1`  вывести из пол напротив в колонке `about_tool` . И так далее пока не переберёт все айдишники. У меня пока что выводит все поля из колонки `about_tool` во все элементы на странице. Может вопрос мой не очень понятный, извините. Но уже 2 сутки бьюсь, не получается ничего. Спасибо

Comment: `SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE id = 1`...тут и цикла не надо, если я вас правильно понял.

Comment: Боюсь без исходного кода будет трудно обнаружить где ошибка.